# Bazel: every command gives unhelpful "Operation not permitted" error

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules

Every command I run using bazel, I get some error to do with a Python library called Scapy.

Trying to run `bazel build <build_rule>`, I get the following unhelpful error message:

```
user@comp:~/Documents/Code/bazel/projects$ bazel build run_testcases
INFO: Analyzed target //projects:run_testcases (39 packages loaded, 303 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/user/Documents/Code/bazel/projects/BUILD:15:10: Creating runfiles tree bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles failed: build-runfiles failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/<hash>/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_202/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/bin \
  /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/install/<hash>/build-runfiles --allow_relative bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles_manifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles): Process exited with status 1: Process exited with status 1
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/install/<hash>/build-runfiles (args bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles_manifest bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles): unlinking 'my_deps_scapy/site-packages/scapy/contrib/rtps/__pycache__/rtps.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied [13]
Target //projects:run_testcases failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.929s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 5 processes: 5 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Even doing something like `bazel clean` gives an error to do with scapy:

```
user@comp:~/Documents/Code/bazel/projects$ bazel clean --expunge
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
ERROR: fchmod (/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/<hash>/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/projects/run_testcases.runfiles/my_deps_scapy/site-packages/scapy/contrib/rtps/__pycache__) (Operation not permitted)
```

Apparently nobody on the internet has had this error, I can't find anything similar anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: It's a generic operating system permissions error not specific to bazel. Check permissions/ownership/etc the same way you would if bazel weren't involved at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding --incompatible_strict_action_env to your bazelrc would help to debug. It will freezes your environment variables and easy way to filter it out and test